# how to open a URL is already opened in another five tabs of same browser using java script?

Tags: javascript, java

I was wondering how could I open a URL which is already lunch in five another tabs in the same browser? I need this as I wanna to do somethings very quickly and do not like spend time for open the address again. I need java script code which does this from chrome council or some where else.

Comment: We do not understand your question. Please try to rephrase it and add detail. For instance, I don't understand why you need to open a URL which is already open in five other tabs? Isn't it enough?

Comment: The reason is that I have to fill out a form in this address and pass it to the server. As there is a huge traffic on the server this fail and I have to do this many time that one of them successes. On the another hand I have to do this in limited time.

Comment: So you basically are looking to DOS a server that is already experiencing high amounts of traffic in order to access it?

Comment: DOS implications aside, you don't open tabs to submit data to a Web server, not if you program an application -- you program initiating HTTP requests. This can be done trivially with JavaScript and you don't need to go to arcane and outright wrong measures to achieve that. Read on the [Fetch API](http://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) and/or [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org) class. Even without JavaScript, one page with a good old HTML form can be submitted multiple times. Your explanation suggests there is more to your question.

Comment: @amn Indeed the problem is that I have submit the form multiple of times that one of them successes. As I said the server is to busy in the time I will submit the form and I have to submit form 5 times or more that one of them get done. Idea of mine was that open multi page and submit form in the tab separately.  Is there any way that I submit a form multiple with one click? I am not a programmer.

Comment: If you are using a computer, you are a programmer. Now, what's wrong with submitting the form on the page, waiting for form response, then seeing if it is successful, and if not going back to the form and trying again? Does the form processing server refuse to process the form 999 out of every 1000 times? Your use-case sounds very pathological and I am not entirely sure about the big picture here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a website in a new tab using chrome console, use the script below. But in order for this to work, you need to allow the pop-ups on your current browser

```
function openWebsite(url,numberOfTabs){
    for(let i=0;i<numberOfTabs;i++){
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
}
openWebsite('http://www.google.com',5)
```

Comment: I would like the java script code automatically catch the address and open it in 5 tabs.